# How do you get python to graph two data frames made from an excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need pandas to read one set of data from an excel sheet, make a bar graph out of it. Then read another set of data from the same sheet and make a bar graph out of that. The problem is that for some reason pandas is reading only the first dataset and no the set one, so I have two identical graphs. Here is the [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpKrC.png). Here are the two datasets.[Dataset1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If1ok.png)  [Dataset2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaJcM.png)

Here's my code.

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  # Used to create a dataframe
import streamlit as st  # Creates a website of the chart when I put streamlit run path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # Makes a graph out of the dataframe
from PIL import Image

st.set_page_config(page_title='Charts')
st.header('Charts')
st.subheader('Bar Chart')  # Use this to label each chart

excel_file = r'C:\Users\CHIRASB1\Downloads\Chart.xlsm'
sheet_name = 'Sheet4'

df1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file,                       # Reads the exel file and creates the data frame
                   sheet_name=sheet_name,  # Calls the sheet obviously
                   usecols='A:Q',  # Selects the columns of the part of the sheet I need
                   header=0,  # Select the top of the section I need
                   dtype=None,  # Makes the, all strings
                   nrows=18)  # Selects the rows in the section I need

y = df1['1-Jun'].tolist()
x = df1['Rule Exception Impacted Apps'].tolist()
st.dataframe(df1)
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.title('Total Rule Impacts vs. Date')  # Creates the chart's title
plt.xticks(rotation=45,  # 27 to 31 is there to prevent the x-axis labels from overlapping
    horizontalalignment='right',  # Changes the horizonal alignment. You can switch it from right to left
    fontweight='light',  # Changes the font weight
    fontsize='medium')  # Changes the font size
plt.tight_layout()

plt.ylabel("Total Rule Impacts")  # labels y-axis
plt.xlabel('Rules')   # labels x-axis

plt.savefig('Chart.png')  # creates a png file of the chart
image = Image.open('Chart.png')  # puts the png file on the streamlit website I made
st.image(image, use_column_width=True)

plt.show()
df2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file,                       # Reads the exel file and creates the data frame
                   sheet_name=sheet_name,   # Calls the sheet obviously
                   usecols='A:Q',  # Selects the columns of the part of the sheet I need
                   header=47,  # Select the top of the section I need
                   dtype=None,  # Makes the, all strings
                   nrows=9)

y = df2['6/1/2021 Monday'].tolist()
x = df2['Rule Exception Impacted Apps1'].tolist()


st.dataframe(df2)

plt.bar(x, y)

plt.title('Blak')  # Creates the chart's title

plt.xticks(rotation=45,
    horizontalalignment='right',
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='x-large')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.ylabel("Blah")  # labels y-axis
plt.xlabel('Blah')

plt.savefig('O.png')  # creates a png file of the chart
image = Image.open('O.png')  # puts the png file on the streamlit website I made
st.image(image, use_column_width=True)
```

Comment: can you try use completely different variables when reading/plotting? for example, `x` and `y` are used in both places.

Comment: I already tried that. Still got the same result.